# How to update request-parameters on API Gateway through cli?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-cli

I am trying to update some values like uri, connId and requestParameters using aws-cli but I'm struggle on this error:

> An error occurred (BadRequestException) when calling the PutIntegration operation: Invalid mapping expression specified: Validation Result: warnings : [], errors : [Invalid mapping expression specified: true, Invalid mapping expression specified: method.request.path.proxy

Here is my command:

```
aws apigateway put-integration \
--rest-api-id pk9ua4hlo9 \
--resource-id j9oi19 \
--integration-http-method 'ANY' \
--http-method 'ANY' \
--type HTTP_PROXY \
--connection-type VPC_LINK \
--connection-id l89vnu \
--uri 'https://aus.gov/mkt/{proxy}' \
--request-parameters "method.request.path.proxy=true"
```

Any idea why this command is wrong? It works if I remove `request-parameters`.